# How to do Sitecore regex 301 redirect by the aliase

Tags: c#, .net, sitecore

Is it possible to do 301 redirect using a reg-ex string with the aliases basically what a want to do is: 
       ordinary aliases use the statut code 200
       if 
       reg-ex aliases use the statut code 301

how can I implement this?
It need absolutely to pass by the aliases request of my client

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this out of the box.
If you're able to customize code for the instance, you need to look into the `Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.AliasResolver` processor in the `httpRequestBegin` pipeline.
Override that processor to add logic for resolving regular expressions in aliases.

If you cannot customize any code, you can look into some modules that are available.

[301 Redirect module](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/301_Redirect_module.aspx)
This one seems to support regular expressions.

[URL Rewriter](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/URL_Rewriter.aspx)
This one is released by me, but doesn't support regular expressions.

And of course there is always the [IIS URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) feature, but that lacks the ability to manage it from Sitecore.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I know it's a uncommon question.